# How to group a pandas dataframe by a defined time interval?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a dataFrame like this, I would like to group every 60 minutes and start grouping at 06:30.

```
                           data
index
2017-02-14 06:29:57    11198648
2017-02-14 06:30:01    11198650
2017-02-14 06:37:22    11198706
2017-02-14 23:11:13    11207728
2017-02-14 23:21:43    11207774
2017-02-14 23:22:36    11207776
```

I am using:

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='60Min'))
```

I get this grouping:

```
                      data
index       
2017-02-14 06:00:00     x1
2017-02-14 07:00:00     x2
2017-02-14 08:00:00     x3
2017-02-14 09:00:00     x4
2017-02-14 10:00:00     x5
```

but I am looking for this result:

```
                      data
index       
2017-02-14 06:30:00     x1
2017-02-14 07:30:00     x2
2017-02-14 08:30:00     x3
2017-02-14 09:30:00     x4
2017-02-14 10:30:00     x5
```

How can I tell the function to start grouping at 6:30 at one-hour intervals?

If it can not be done by the *.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='60Min'))*, how is the best way to do it?

A salute and thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `base=30` in conjunction with `label='right'` parameters in [`pd.Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html).

Specifying `label='right'` makes the time-period to start grouping from 6:30 (higher side) and not 5:30. 
Also, `base` is set to 0 [by default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), hence the need to offset those by 30 to account for the forward propagation of dates.

Suppose, you want to aggregate the first element of every sub-group, then:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min', base=30, label='right')).first()
# same thing using resample - df.resample('60Min', base=30, label='right').first()
```

yields:

```
                           data
index                          
2017-02-14 06:30:00  11198648.0
2017-02-14 07:30:00  11198650.0
2017-02-14 08:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 09:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 10:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 11:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 12:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 13:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 14:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 15:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 16:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 17:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 18:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 19:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 20:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 21:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 22:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 23:30:00  11207728.0
```

Comment: Why is there no documentation for this function in Pandas? Is there any way to see the code of the pd.TimeGrouper function?? I remember that in R you could see the code writting the function name without parentheses, is there something like that in python??

Comment: [Complete code of `pd.TimeGrouper`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/groupby.py#L156-L312). It inherits some of the `**kwargs` from [Complete code of `resample`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/generic.py#L4068-L4216) too (for eg: `base`).

Comment: If you're on Jupyter, `help(pd.TimeGrouper)` would also give you a short description regarding it's usage, data descriptors, parameters allowed, methods defined etc.

Comment: There's a deprecation warning now. I guess use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html now if you want to expect simple upgrades

Comment: Now *base* is deprecated, you should use **offset** instead

Answer (score 8):

Using [`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) which is a dedicated method for resampling time series, this way we dont need `DataFrame.GroupBy` and `pd.Grouper`:

```
df.resample('60min', base=30, label='right').first()
```

**Output**

```
                           data
index                          
2017-02-14 06:30:00  11198648.0
2017-02-14 07:30:00  11198650.0
2017-02-14 08:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 09:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 10:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 11:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 12:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 13:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 14:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 15:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 16:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 17:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 18:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 19:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 20:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 21:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 22:30:00         NaN
2017-02-14 23:30:00  11207728.0
```

---

**Notice**: when you have multiple columns in your dataframe, you have to specify the column you want to aggregate on:

```
df.resample('60min', base=30, label='right')['data'].first()
```

Comment: FutureWarning: 'base' in .resample() and in Grouper() is deprecated.
The new arguments that you should use are 'offset' or 'origin'.

Comment: This is great! and sort of the thing I am looking for. However, I want it to group by hour starting at the value first in the dataframe. e.g. if the first timing is 9:17, I wish it to group by 9:17-10:17, would this just mean changing the base to the first minute in the dataframe?