# How to count the number of rows in a given time interval in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with a numer of columns that contain timestamps for certain events that can happen to objects, where the object IDs index the rows.

```
obj_id | event1  |  event2  |  event3  |  ...
1      | datetime| datetime |  NaT     |  ...
...    | ...     | ...      |  ...     |  ...
```

I want to count the number of occurences of an event over the course of the day (discarding the date), in intervals I specify.

Sor far, I solve this by recunstructing the number of minutes since midnight using `datetime.hour` and `datetime.minute`:

```
i = 5    # number of minutes in the interval I'm interested in
ev1_counts = df.groupby(
                        df.event1.apply(lambda x: i * ((60*x.hour + x.minute)//i))
                        )['event1'].count()
```

This does the job, but it seems unpythonic and I'm sure there is a better way. But how?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval), but trying

```
time_series = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.event1)
ts_df =  pd.Series([1]*len(time_series), index=time_series)
ev1_counts = ts_df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq = '{:d}Min'.format(i)).count()
```

Keeps the date information, which I want to discard. Converting the `pd.datetime` objects with the `.time()` method seems problematic, since the result can not be treated as a datetime object.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum sample of data, and the outcome you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can omit `apply` and simplify solution to:

```
ev1_counts = df.groupby((60*df.event1.dt.hour+df.event1.dt.minute)//i * i)['event1'].count()
```