# Pandas monthly rolling operation

Tags: python, pandas

I ended up figuring it out while writing out this question so I'll just post anyway and answer my own question in case someone else needs a little help.

### Problem

Suppose we have a `DataFrame`, `df`, containing this data.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(
"""\
date          spendings  category
2014-03-25    10         A
2014-04-05    20         A
2014-04-15    10         A
2014-04-25    10         B
2014-05-05    10         B
2014-05-15    10         A
2014-05-25    10         A
"""
)

df = pd.read_csv(data,sep="\s+",parse_dates=True,index_col="date")
```

### Goal

For each row, sum the `spendings` over every row that is within **one month** of it, ideally using `DataFrame.rolling` as it's a very clean syntax.

### What I have tried

```
df = df.rolling("M").sum()
```

But this throws an exception

```
ValueError: <MonthEnd> is a non-fixed frequency
```

version: `pandas==0.19.2`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `"D"` offset rather than `"M"` and specifically use `"30D"` for 30 days or approximately one month.

```
df = df.rolling("30D").sum()
```

Initially, I intuitively jumped to using `"M"` as I figured it stands for one month, but now it's clear why that doesn't work.

Comment: Could you explain why it's clear? I don't understand it, and I can't find anything in the documentation about it. I get the same error if I use "1AS" (beginning of year)

Comment: Note: I haven't looked at this in a while. A rolling window must have a fixed width - "a month" is not a fixed number of days. Consider how the rolling operation given above works: for each row, take the surrounding rows that are within 30 days and sum them. If instead it were: for each row, take the surrounding rows that are within "one month" and sum them, how would the algorithm determine the length of that month? 28 days? 30 days? 31 days?

Comment: So it only works for frequencies that are "days" or smaller (e.g. hours, minutes, seconds)? I just tried "2W" for weeks, and that doesn't work either, even though a week is always 7 days

Comment: Seems like that's the case. I don't think a week is always 7 days necessarily. Depending on the calendar system used, sometimes the last week in the year isn't exactly 7 days or the first week in the year isn't. I'm not sure about this, just remember reading this somewhere a while ago.

Comment: @FilipKilibarda Does 'take the surrounding rows that are within 30 days' mean within 30 days before the date of the current row AND 30 days ahead of the date of the current row?

Comment: @derNincompoop No. The size of the window is 30 days. You can center the rolling window such that it takes +-15 days of the current row with the center=True parameter. It's described in the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: Selecting via 'M' actually works if you do it with `pandas.Grouper`. See this stack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256129/1445572

Comment: The [current documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) states that _If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window. Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in the time-period._ So in principle variable window sizes are now possible?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé but `Grouper` appears not to work with `rolling` 

Answer (score 25):

To address why you cannot use things like "AS" or "Y", in this case, "Y" offset is not "a year", it is actually referencing YearEnd (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases), and therefore the rolling function does not get a fixed window (e.g. you get a 365 day window if your index falls on Jan 1, and 1 day if Dec 31).

The proposed solution (offset by 30D) works if you do not need strict calendar months. Alternatively, you would iterate over your date index, and slice with an offset to get more precise control over your sum.

If you have to do it in one line (separated for readability):

```
df['Sum'] = [
    df.loc[
        edt - pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=1):edt, 'spendings'
    ].sum() for edt in df.index
]
spendings   category    Sum
date            
2014-03-25  10  A   10
2014-04-05  20  A   30
2014-04-15  10  A   40
2014-04-25  10  B   50
2014-05-05  10  B   50
2014-05-15  10  A   40
2014-05-25  10  A   40
```

Comment: This method is actually very slow, else a good answer. I was looking out for a vectorized method. (My single df of ~1.5K rows take ~1s and I have ~25K dfs to process!)