# Python rolling Sharpe ratio with Pandas or NumPy

Tags: pandas, finance, moving-average

I am trying to generate a plot of the 6-month **rolling** Sharpe ratio using Python with Pandas/NumPy.

My input data is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# Generate sample data
d = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2008', end='12/1/2015')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Date'])
df['returns'] = np.random.rand(d.size, 1)
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df.head(20))

             returns
Date                
2008-01-01  0.232794
2008-01-02  0.957157
2008-01-03  0.079939
2008-01-04  0.772999
2008-01-05  0.708377
2008-01-06  0.579662
2008-01-07  0.998632
2008-01-08  0.432605
2008-01-09  0.499041
2008-01-10  0.693420
2008-01-11  0.330222
2008-01-12  0.109280
2008-01-13  0.776309
2008-01-14  0.079325
2008-01-15  0.559206
2008-01-16  0.748133
2008-01-17  0.747319
2008-01-18  0.936322
2008-01-19  0.211246
2008-01-20  0.755340
```

**What I want**

The type of plot I am trying to produce is [this](http://awealthofcommonsense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Sharpe-III.png) or [the first plot from here](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/intraday-algorithm-us-equities-4-dot-5-sharpe) (see below).
[image]

**My attempt**

Here is the equation I am using:

```
def my_rolling_sharpe(y):
    return np.sqrt(126) * (y.mean() / y.std()) # 21 days per month X 6 months = 126

# Calculate rolling Sharpe ratio
df['rs'] = calc_sharpe_ratio(df['returns'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 3))
df['rs'].plot(style='-', lw=3, color='indianred', label='Sharpe')\
        .axhline(y = 0, color = "black", lw = 3)

plt.ylabel('Sharpe ratio')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Rolling Sharpe ratio (6-month)')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The problem is that I am getting a horizontal line since my function is giving a single value for the Sharpe ratio. This value is the same for all the Dates. In the example plots, they appear to be showing many ratios.

**Question**

Is it possible to plot a 6-month rolling Sharpe ratio that changes from one day to the next?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Approximately correct solution using `df.rolling` and a fixed window size of 180 days:

```
df['rs'] = df['returns'].rolling('180d').apply(my_rolling_sharpe)
```

This window isn't exactly 6 calendar months wide because `rolling` requires a fixed window size, so trying `window='6MS'` (6 **M**onth **S**tarts) throws a ValueError.

To calculate the Sharpe ratio for a window exactly 6 calendar months wide, I'll copy [this super cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199274) by SO user Mike:

```
df['rs2'] = [my_rolling_sharpe(df.loc[d - pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=6):d, 'returns']) 
             for d in df.index]

# Compare the two windows
df.plot(y=['rs', 'rs2'], linewidth=0.5)
```

[image: Sharpe ratio comparison]

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared an alternative solution to your question, this one is based on using solely the [window functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html) from pandas.

Here I have defined "on the fly" the calculation of the Sharpe Ratio, please consider for your solution the following parameters:

- I have used a Risk Free rate of **2%**
- The dash line is just a Benchmark for the rolling Sharpe Ratio, the value is **1.6**

So the code is the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

# Generate sample data
d = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2008', end='12/1/2015')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['Date'])
df['returns'] = np.random.rand(d.size, 1)
df = df.set_index('Date')

df['rolling_SR'] = df.returns.rolling(180).apply(lambda x: (x.mean() - 0.02) / x.std(), raw = True)
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df[df['rolling_SR'] > 0].rolling_SR.plot(style='-', lw=3, color='orange', 
                                         label='Sharpe', figsize = (10,7))\
                                         .axhline(y = 1.6, color = "blue", lw = 3,
                                                 linestyle = '--')

plt.ylabel('Sharpe ratio')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Rolling Sharpe ratio (6-month)')
plt.show()

print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
print('In case you want to check the result data\n')
print(df.tail()) # I use tail, beacause of the size of your window.
```

You should get something similar to this picture

[image: rolling sharpe ratio]