# Pandas DataFrame custom rolling function that sees index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, rolling-computation

I want to apply an offset rolling window function on a DataFrame with a date index.  Here's an example:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-01-03', periods=20, freq='W')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20), rng, columns=['Val'])
df.index.name = 'Date'
r = df.rolling('15D')
```

This produces a DataFrame `df` like:

```
                 Val
Date                
2017-01-08  0.592210
2017-01-15 -1.243938
2017-01-22 -0.713988
2017-01-29  1.554777
...
```

But I can't figure out how to see the Date associated with each Val in any function I apply to the `Rolling` window.  For example, the following:

```
def f(data=None): # I really want to reference the Date associated with each Val in here!
    print('f(%s) data=%s' % (str(type(data)), data))        
    return 1
r.apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

shows that all I get to see is an `ndarray` for each call:

```
f(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) data=[0.59220959]
f(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) data=[ 0.59220959 -1.24393841]
f(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) data=[ 0.59220959 -1.24393841 -0.71398767]
f(<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) data=[-1.24393841 -0.71398767  1.55477737]
...
```

Is there a way to invoke a time offset rolling window on a DataFrame in such a way that the aggregation function sees the index associated with each value in the window?

E.g., so that I can apply a function that sees something like:

```
f(<class 'DataFrame'>) data=[{2017-01-08, 0.59221}]
f(<class 'DataFrame'>) data=[{2017-01-08, 0.59221}, {2017-01-15, -1.243938}]
...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible in the recent version with `.apply(..., raw=False)`

The trick is to define a function that has access to your entire dataframe. Then you do a roll on any column and call `apply()` passing in that function. The function will have access to the window data, which is a subset of the dataframe column. From that subset you can extract the index you should be looking at. (This assumes that your index is strictly increasing. So the usual integer index will work, as well as most time series.) You can use the index to then access the entire dataframe with all the columns.

```
def dataframe_roll(df):
    def my_fn(window_series):
        # Note: you can do any kind of offset here
        window_df = df[(df.index >= window_series.index[0]) & (df.index <= window_series.index[-1])]
        return window_df["col1"] + window_df["col2"]
    return my_fn

df["result"] = df["any_col"].rolling(24).apply(dataframe_roll(df), raw=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this with just `pd.rolling`. Here's a workaround inspired by [a recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091044/python-rolling-sharpe-ratio-with-pandas-or-numpy/49091199#49091199):

```
s = pd.Series([df.loc[d - pd.offsets.DateOffset(days=15):d, 'Val'] for d in df.index])
```

This will build a Series of Series, where each sub-Series contains the Date and Val you want your function to see.  I.e., with your sample function, `s.apply(f)` produces:

```
f(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>) data=Date
2017-01-08   -1.662699
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Val, dtype: float64
f(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>) data=Date
2017-01-08   -1.662699
2017-01-15    0.478471
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Val, dtype: float64
f(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>) data=Date
2017-01-08   -1.662699
2017-01-15    0.478471
2017-01-22   -0.552616
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Val, dtype: float64
f(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>) data=Date
2017-01-15    0.478471
2017-01-22   -0.552616
2017-01-29   -2.190669
...
```