# pandas: Why doesn't rolling work in this case where I am doing a group-by followed by rolling `n`m aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4, 10], "id" : [1,1,1,2,2,2]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 00:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130201 00:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130301 00:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130301 00:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130401 00:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130501 00:00:00')])


df.groupby("id").rolling("2m").agg(["mean"])
```

in which I am just doing a rolling 2 month average of numeric values grouped by `"id"`. The error message is `ValueError: <2 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency`

What's the issue here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas monthly rolling operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556344/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation)

Comment: "M" is not considered as a fixed time frame as some months as the number of days can be 30 or 31 days. The rolling function does not work that way. I have encountered this problem and used the "D" frequency (days) to solve it. So, just give an approx. number of days for the months you are looking at. Maybe there is a different explanation.