# Pandas groupy by last 6 months from a reference date

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sum a column "qtd" taking into account the last 6 months of a reference date.

```
prod    date       qtd  sum
proda   2018-01-01  2    2
proda   2018-02-01  2    4
proda   2018-04-01  1    5
proda   2018-05-01  4    9
proda   2018-06-01  2    11
proda   2018-07-01  1    11
```

I need to figure out how to calculate the column "sum".

Note that I don't always have every month on my dataframe, for example I don't have March.
Given a reference date (date) I need to calculate 6 months back and sum the column "qtd"

Thanks!

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: are you looking for `cumsum()`

Comment: should the sum for the last row be 10 and not 11? if yes, you are probably looking for `resample` and sum with a window of 6 months

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas monthly rolling operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556344/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47199274/13386979) specifically.  And agree with @Ben.T - you are either going to get a sum of 10 for last row (6 months ago excluded) or 12 (6 months ago included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cumsum( ) function will bring you the cumulative sum for a given column. From numpy.

```
df[‘sum’] = df[‘qtd’].cumsum()
```

Ok. In case you want to extract only the slice and calc cumsum(), you can use:

```
start_date = '2018-01-01'
end_date = '2018-05-01'
between = (df['date'] >= start_date) & (df['date'] <= end_date)
df2 = df[between]
df2['sum'] = df2['qtd'].cumsum()

df2

    prod    date        qtd sum
0   proda   2018-01-01  2   2
1   proda   2018-02-01  2   4
2   proda   2018-04-01  1   5
3   proda   2018-05-01  4   9
```

Or if you want to calculate it only between specific dates and add it to your data frame, you can use:

```
start_date = '2/1/18'
end_date = '6/1/18'

def total(start, end, df):
    sum_col = []
    for i in range(df.shape[0]): # Loop for all lines
        if df['date'][i] < start:
  # If before start date, NA (you could change to 0 too)
            sum_col.append('NaN')
        elif df['date'][i] == start: # start to sum
            sum_col.append(df['qtd'][I])
  #sum between your start and end dates
        elif (df['date'][i] > start) and (df['date'][i] <= end): 
            sum_col.append(df['qtd'][i]+sum_col[i-1])
  # after end date, it just adds NAs. You can change to repeat the last total
        elif df['date'][i] > end:
            sum_col.append('NaN')
    return sum_col

df['sum'] = total(start_date, end_date, df)

df
```

output:

```
    prod    date    qtd sum
0   proda   1/1/18  2   NaN
1   proda   2/1/18  2   2
2   proda   4/1/18  1   3
3   proda   5/1/18  4   7
4   proda   6/1/18  2   9
5   proda   7/1/18  1   NaN
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't handle the previous 6 months aspect of the questions, say if the time series were longer

Comment: I have just updated my answer, hoping I answered your question...