# Rolling moving average using Datetime.Offset

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, datetimeoffset

I have a timeseries of daily data that I want to take a rolling average of a certain period. Is it possible to do this with `Datetime.Offset`?

The code may look like:

```
l = [7.71, 7.79, 6.80, 6.44, 6.46, 6.80] 

index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', 
                      '2017-01-04' ,'2017-01-05' ,'2017-01-06'])

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['col'], index = index)
```

I want the calculate the yearly mean of the timeseries. With the above numbers the output should be as follows:

```
2017-01-04  7.185
2017-01-05  6.873
2017-01-05  6.625
```

I tried to write as follows

```
df.rolling(window=1, freq='A').mean()
```

but gets the following error message:

```
TypeError: rolling() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
```

I have also tried the following:

```
do = pd.DateOffset(years = 1)

eps.rolling(window=do).mean()
```

but gets the following error message:

```
ValueError: <DateOffset: years=1> is a non-fixed frequency
```

Is this possible to do with rollong or should I try another approach ?

Comment: Could you confirm how the desired output is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your errors is that `rolling` does not take a `freq` argument. To use an annual rolling window you have to use `365D` as explained also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556344/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation). The issue is that `1Y` might have different number of days, i.e., the frequency is "non-fixed".

In your case this will translate to

```
df.rolling('365D').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your index to DatetimeIndex.

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Groupby the month and day and calculate the mean

```py
df_ = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
```

```py
# print(df_)

       col
1 4  7.075
  5  7.125
  6  6.800
```

If you want to get a normal index, you can do

```py
df_ = df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).mean()
df_ = df_.reset_index()
df_['month-day'] = df_['level_0'].astype(str) + '-' + df_['level_1'].astype(str)
df_.drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

```
# print(df_)

     col month-day
0  7.075       1-4
1  7.125       1-5
2  6.800       1-6
```

Or you can create a new column with month and day

```py
df['month-day'] = df.index.strftime('%m-%d')
df_ = df.groupby('month-day').mean().reset_index()
```

```
# print(df_)

  month-day    col
0     01-04  7.075
1     01-05  7.125
2     01-06  6.800
```