# conditional while loop to sum subsequent rows of data based on column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, nested-loops

A given data set is ordered by [`Dates`] and grouped by [`Code`].

For each set of `Value`'s (grouped by `Code`), I would like to sum the values 9 months in advance. For instance, row 0's new value would be the summation of all rows with the same code "123" that are 9 months in advance which is rows 0,1 & 2 so the sum of row 0's new value is 1+2+3. Here is a sample of the data for better clarity.

```
   Dates      Value  Code  Value(rolling 9Months) 
0  01/31/2021   1      123   (1+2+3)
1  03/31/2021   2      123   (2+3+4)
2  09/30/2021   3      123   (3+4)
3  12/31/2021   4      123   (4)
4  02/28/2021   1      345   (1+2+5)
5  05/31/2021   2      345   (2+5)
6  09/30/2021   5      345   (5)
```

I figure the pseudo code would read something like this (apologies for the novitiate) --

```
While Code is constant
    If (datei+1 – datei) <= 9
    Then sum values with same code
```

Happy to elaborate on any point, thank you greatly for any help!

Comment: I see what you mean: the solution that I suggested earlier only worked accidentally. I'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. The following will work *only* if each month per unique `Code` value has only *one* associated date. E.g. it won't work, if you could have both `'01/30/2021'` and `'01/31/2021'` for `123`.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Dates': {0: '01/31/2021', 1: '03/31/2021', 2: '09/30/2021',
                  3: '12/31/2021', 4: '02/28/2021', 5: '05/31/2021', 
                  6: '09/30/2021'},
        'Value': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 5},
        'Code': {0: 123, 1: 123, 2: 123, 3: 123, 4: 345, 5: 345, 6: 345}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# turn col `Dates` into datetime
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

# set `Dates` as index
df.set_index('Dates', drop=True, inplace=True)

def roll(x):
    # flip x (a `pd.Series` for col `Value`), apply rolling, and sum
    # window == 279D (i.e. 9*31)
    # min_periods == 1 (actually, the default)
    return x[::-1].rolling('279D', min_periods=1).sum()

# first turn all dates into `EoM`, groupby `Code`, select col `Value`
# call func `roll` inside `transform` to ensure result respects 
# order of orig index; copy only `to_numpy`, since index will not match,
# (but it will be the same order)
df['Value_rolling_9months'] = df.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')\
    .groupby('Code')['Value'].transform(roll).to_numpy()

print(df)

            Value  Code  Value_rolling_9months
Dates                                         
2021-01-31      1   123                    6.0
2021-03-31      2   123                    9.0
2021-09-30      3   123                    7.0
2021-12-31      4   123                    4.0
2021-02-28      1   345                    8.0
2021-05-31      2   345                    7.0
2021-09-30      5   345                    5.0
```

If you 100% sure that your dates are always already `EoM` (as in your example), then you could simply use:

```
df['Value_rolling_9months'] = df.groupby('Code')['Value'].transform(roll)
```

**Simplified example**

We are flipping the frame for each group in `df.Code`. E.g.:

```
print(df.loc[df.Code == 345, 'Value'][::-1])

Dates
2021-09-30    5
2021-05-31    2
2021-02-28    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Now, we want to apply [`.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a window of "9 months"; unfortunately, if you try to roll on one or more *months*, you will receive an error. E.g.

```
df.loc[df.Code == 345, 'Value'][::-1].rolling('9M')
# ValueError: <9 * MonthEnds> is a non-fixed frequency
```

For the reason, see this [`SO post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556344/pandas-monthly-rolling-operation). To circumvent this issue, we can roll by dates. Since we have *only* `EoM` values, we can do this safely; there will always be a considerable gap between two consecutive dates.

To see what is actually happening with `rolling`, we can `list` the procedure. E.g.:

```
list(df.loc[df.Code == 345, 'Value'][::-1].rolling('279D', min_periods=1))

[Dates
 2021-09-30    5
 Name: Value, dtype: int64,
 Dates
 2021-09-30    5
 2021-05-31    2
 Name: Value, dtype: int64,
 Dates
 2021-09-30    5
 2021-05-31    2
 2021-02-28    1
 Name: Value, dtype: int64]
```

For each of these `windows`, we are asking the `sum`. The parameter `min_periods=1` means that we allow summing at a minimum of `1 observation`. E.g., suppose we would set it to `2`, then we would get a `NaN value` returned for the first window.

So, here the sum will get us `5, 7, 8`. Note that these values would be in the incorrect order, we actually need `8, 7, 5`. This is where [`DataFrameGroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) comes in: it ensures that the result is returned in the same order as the original index.

Comment: Hi thank you so much @ouroboros1, can you kindly explain what ".rolling(window=3, min_periods=1) means ? particularly the windows and min periods? Thanks!

Comment: it seems that the rolling 9 month condition is not being taken into consideration. Coincidently the window & period method works for this data set but at scale it seems it is counting rows and not calculating if the next row is within the 9 month window or not.

Comment: Updated the answer. N.B. I interpret your window here as follows: if we have a date `2021-01-01`, we want to sum *through to and including* `2021-10-31`. This should work with `'279D'`. If you actually mean *through to and including* `2021-09-30`, you need to subtract one approx. month, so use `'248D'` in that case (8*31).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea: Basically, reindex each group into monthly intervals (fill the extra rows with 0s), compute the rolling sum with a window of 10 months, then merge the result with the original dataframe so only the desired rows remain.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': [Timestamp('2021-01-31 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-03-31 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-12-31 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-02-28 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-05-31 00:00:00'),
                             Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00')],
                             'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5],
                             'Code': [123, 123, 123, 123, 345, 345, 345]})
```

```py
def get_rolling_sum(frame):
    
    # set the index to monthly values and fill NaNs with 0s
    frame = frame.reindex(
        pd.date_range(frame.index.min(), frame.index.max(), freq="M")
    ).fillna(0)

    # compute the rolling sum of 10-month-long intervals on the reverse
    return frame[::-1].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).sum()

df_tmp = (df
          .set_index("Dates") # set Dates as index for the reindexing
          .groupby("Code")
          .Value.apply(get_rolling_sum)
          .reset_index() # turn the Dates and Code index into regular columns again
          .rename(columns={"level_1": "Dates", "Value": "Value9M"})
         )
```

Finally, merge the result with the original dataframe:

```py
>>> df.merge(df_tmp, on=["Dates", "Code"])
       Dates  Value  Code  Value9M
0 2021-01-31      1   123      6.0
1 2021-03-31      2   123      9.0
2 2021-09-30      3   123      7.0
3 2021-12-31      4   123      4.0
4 2021-02-28      1   345      8.0
5 2021-05-31      2   345      7.0
6 2021-09-30      5   345      5.0
```