# Split a dataframe by time column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select the right portion of a dataset as explain with the following example:

input df:

```
id_B, ts_B,value
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:40,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:50,1
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:00,4
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:10,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:20,100
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:30,155
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:40,235
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:50,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:36:60,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:00,2353
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:10,221
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:20,2432
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:30,2654
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:40,12
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:50,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:00,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:10,23
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:20,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:30,2
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:40,2
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:50,1
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:10,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:20,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:30,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:40,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:50,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:00,0
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:10,1
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:20,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:30,221
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:40,2432
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:50,2654 
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:60,12
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:00,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:10,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:20,23
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:30,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:40,2
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:50,1
```

considering the following: 
  segment_number = 1
  duration = 3 minuts

I want to select the first segment of the dataframe starting from the first df.value non zero until the last value covering the duration of 3 minutes.

output: 
    
    `id1,2017-04-27 01:35:50,1
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:00,4
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:10,5
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:20,100
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:30,155
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:40,235
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:50,0
    id1,2017-04-27 01:36:60,0
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:00,2353
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:10,221
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:20,2432
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:30,2654
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:40,12
    id1,2017-04-27 01:37:50,5
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:00,5
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:10,23
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:20,5
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:30,2
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:40,2
    id1,2017-04-27 01:38:50,1`

considering the following: 
  segment_number = 2
  duration = 1.40 minuts

I want to select the second segment of the dateframe starting from the first df.value non zero until the last value covering the duration of 1.40 minutes.

output:

```
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:10,1
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:20,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:30,221
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:40,2432
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:50,2654 
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:60,12
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:00,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:10,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:20,23
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:30,5
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:40,2
id1,2017-04-27 01:41:50,1
```

so far, I did indexed df w.r.t to the ts_B by using `pd.to_datetime and set_index' and using a variable "last_end_point" that keeps track of the index of the previous segment.
But I do not get the right output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, do you want to split your `df` by decremental time interval?

Comment: yes, sort of. more specifically, I would like to split it by duration and a starting point, where the first time is from the beginning, second time is the index of the last row of the previous time.

Comment: sorry, the last raw of the previous segment +1. But it should avoid starting the segment with df.value =0  and select always the first that is not zero.

Comment: In your first output, you wanted 3 minutes, but you have every minute in your output. What is your end goal? Getting a `sum` or `mean` of each time interval to model a time-series??

Comment: I want all the time-series that covers the duration of 3 minutes. The final goal is that I need to merge that portion of the df with another one. But I need to select it first.

Comment: See this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval , read that documentation to set your `base` for `3min` interval and so forth. Comment, if this was helpful.

Comment: Uhhmmm...quite far from what I am looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am also using the np.nonzero but I am getting no where.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151904/discussion-between-carlo-allocca-and-i-n-n-m).

Comment: I am trying to write a function: df = sample_df.set_index(keys=['ts_datetime'])
df1=df.loc[lambda df: df.value > 0 and df.index.get_level_values(0).values > "start-date" and df.index.get_level_values(0).values < "start-date" + duration]

Comment: Please, any help on this? it would be very appreciated.

Comment: how did you get the `duration` from? what are you trying to accomplish in the above code? what error are you getting? Sorry, still not clear to me!

Comment: the duration in an input parameter. I am trying to write a function find_the_segment(self, key, duration, energenie_df,last_ended_index, threshold):

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I formulated:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df['ts_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts_B'])  

def find_the_energenies_segment(key_mapped, duration, energenie_df, threshold):
    non_zero_indexs = energenie_df[energenie_df["value"]>threshold].index 

    first_index = non_zero_indexs[0]  if len(non_zero_indexs)>0 else None


    if(not first_index):
       return {"sub_df": None,
           "start_index": None,
           "end_index":None,
           "duration": duration}

    start_time = energenie_df.loc[first_index].ts_B 
    hours,minutes,seconds = duration.split(":")
    end_time = start_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(hours),minutes=int(minutes),seconds=int(seconds))


    last_index = energenie_df[energenie_df["ts_B"]>end_time].index[0]-1 

    return {"sub_df": energenie_df.loc[first_index:last_index],
       "start_index": first_index,
       "end_index":last_index,
       "duration": duration}


out = find_the_energenies_segment("id1", "00:03:00", df, 0 )
print(out)
```