# Pandas, sequential search in non indexed csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a large .csv opened with Pandas.
It has 2 columns, column "a" is a timpestamp (Unix timestamp), column "b" is the value.
The data are high-frequecy, (around 1 point/second) but not evenly spaced, sometimes is 5 points per seconds, sometimes is 1 point every 5 seconds.

I need to scale it down to 1 point every 5 minutes give or take a few seconds but due to the uneven nature of the the spacing the only way I can envision to do it is as follows:

-Read the value of the first timestamp

-Go thru all the following timestamps until I find one with a value equal or higher than the value of the first one +300 seconds. Print timestamp + value to the output file

-Look for the next data points, searching for the first ones with timestamps equal or higher than the first timestamp + 300*N seconds.

In order to do this I need to access the lines of the .csv with some sort of "index", enumerating them would probably be fine.

How to do this? I`d do it in seconds in Sql but I am pretty lost here.

*Edit: to clear that this is not a duplicate, the question can be more reformulated in a more abstract way as "how to arbitrarily index an imported dataset."*

Comment: Why don'y you code it up and see how it works and post again if you have any problems?

Comment: how do you want to downsample it? Do you want to have an average (mean) / min / max / first /last value at the end?

Comment: It seems like you're just using Pandas as a csv-reading tool and leaving it at that. In fact, it comes pre-loaded with all the methods you need to do what you require. Using [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) you can get it to automatically section your data into 5 min intervals (though I find the docs on Grouper to be poorly explained, and originally it was done with TimeGrouper so you'll probably have to search a bit for a working method)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group a pandas dataframe by a defined time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval)

Comment: Thank you all - I am getting started with Pandas and will explore its functions, this is my first step. I am not looking to make an average, I want the value (with a dynamic much slower that ~5s) of the instantaneous reading at that time.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz, when doing a resampling you must decide what values do you want to pick from within each interval (5 minutes in your case) - first / last / min / max / mean / any random value...

Comment: @MaxU Thanks! I'll try over the weekend and report back/accept answer on Monday.

Comment: @MaxU your answer solved my problem (and got me hooked on Pandas :-) ) thanks

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz, welcome to the Pandas Lovers Club! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done fairly easily using Pandas methods:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
# convert UNIX timestamp to datetime
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('a'), unit='s', errors='coerce')
df.resample('5T').mean().to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: This seems what I am looking for. Just I do not want to go for the "mean", I'd like to have the exact value. I'll use this piece of code and report back. Thankyou.