# How do you get the sum of miles using dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
index   date           miles
0   7/8/2015 14:00:00   10
1   7/8/2015 15:00:01   2
2   7/8/2015 16:00:01   5
3   7/9/2015 09:00:02   12
4   7/10/2015 12:00:00  4
5   7/11/2015 11:00:00  25
6   7/12/2015 04:34:33  10
7   7/12/2015 05:35:35  22
8   7/12/2015 23:11:11  14
9   7/13/2015 01:00:23  10
10  7/13/2015 03:00:03  2
```

I want to make this table to following;

```
7/8/2015    17
7/9/2015    12
7/10/2015   4
7/11/2015   25
7/12/2015   46
7/13/2015   12
```

How can i make something like this in python? Group by date to get sum of miles of each day

Comment: Did you try with `df.groupby('date').sum()`?

Comment: @Valentino yeah, but it doesn't group by date..

Comment: Yes, it does. It works for me. Try again, if you get an error add the traceback to your question.

Comment: i guess I didn't mentions time,min,sec after date. Thats why its not working. your code doesn't work if there is time,min,sec @Valentino

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group a pandas dataframe by a defined time interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval)

Comment: Or using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) too

Answer (score 0):

As @Valentino mentionned:

```
data = {
    'date': ['7/8/2015 14:00:00', '7/8/2015 14:00:00', '7/8/2015 14:00:00', '7/9/2015 14:00:00'],
    'miles': [10, 2, 5, 12]
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df.date)

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

print(df)

Out:
date    miles
0   7/8/2015    10
1   7/8/2015    2
2   7/8/2015    5
3   7/9/2015    12
```

```
print(df.groupby('date').sum())

Out:
date    miles   
7/8/2015    17
7/9/2015    12
```

Comment: do you know how if there is time after date?

Comment: what do you mean *time after date*?

Comment: @JonathanGuymont look at his update above. His datetime format changed.

Comment: just edited my post but i forgot to mention there is hours-min-seconds after date

Answer (score 0):

If you asked about a solution to add the miles of same day in one line .A way to do it is to go through all of the dates using (for loop) and add all that are equal or basically the same date to a variable then print each line

Answer (score 0):

Using [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
ddf = df.resample('1D').sum()
```

`resample` needs a datetime index, so you need to set the index to `'date'` before.

If `df` is your sample input, `ddf` will look:

```
            miles
date             
2015-07-08     17
2015-07-09     12
2015-07-10      4
2015-07-11     25
2015-07-12     46
2015-07-13     12
```