# Pandas - slice data and calculate averages

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a parcel delivery data sheet looks like below structure:

```
route_id      parcel_id   loading_time           other_fields
  X1          001         14:20 25/07/2019       ...
  X2          025         14:23 25/07/2019       ...
...         ...                    ...
```

I would like to compute the average of all parcel's weight appeared in every 10 minutes (0-10, 11-20, 21-30) by each route_id. So the result sheet I want looks like:

```
route_id        time_window                                         average_weight(kg)
   X1           870 (i.e. 14:20 - 14:30，only show UpperBound)      550 
   X1           880                                                 1020
   ...          ...                                                 ...
```

How to do this easily in Pandas or in SQL server?

Comment: We may need more info about it

Comment: what information do you want? I just want to compute the average parcel volume appeared in every 10 min throughout the day, by each route_id.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to perform aggregations by `route_id` at 10-minute intervals. Also your `loading_time` is a string. Convert it to `Timestamp` first.

The example below uses some mock data since there was no sample input data:

```
loading_times = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-07-25 9:00', '2019-07-25 9:20', freq='T'), 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'route_id': np.random.randint(1, 4, len(loading_times)),
    'weight': np.random.randint(1, 5, len(loading_times)),
    'loading_time': loading_times
})
```

Sample data (sorted):

```
route_id  weight        loading_time
       1       2 2019-07-25 09:00:00
       1       1 2019-07-25 09:07:00
       1       4 2019-07-25 09:10:00
       1       1 2019-07-25 09:12:00
       1       2 2019-07-25 09:13:00
       1       2 2019-07-25 09:15:00
       1       3 2019-07-25 09:19:00
       2       4 2019-07-25 09:03:00
       3       4 2019-07-25 09:04:00
       3       3 2019-07-25 09:17:00
```

Then group it:

```
def summarize(x):
    return pd.Series({
        'count': len(x),
        'avg_weight': x['weight'].mean()
    })

by = ['route_id', pd.Grouper(key='loading_time', freq='10T')]
df.groupby(by).apply(summarize)
```

Result:

```
                              count  avg_weight
route_id loading_time                          
1        2019-07-25 09:00:00    2.0         1.5
         2019-07-25 09:10:00    5.0         2.4
2        2019-07-25 09:00:00    1.0         4.0
3        2019-07-25 09:00:00    1.0         4.0
         2019-07-25 09:10:00    1.0         3.0
```

Comment: I have edited my question. 1). I want to get the average of parcels in a defined period (every 10 min, 0-10, 11-20, 21-30). Is the loading_time in your final result the upper bound of the time interval?  2). how to replicate the route_id in the index?

Comment: (1) the `loading_time` in the output above is the starting time of the period (i.e. from 9:00 to before 9:10, from 9:10 to before 9:20, etc.). (2) it's cut for display only. The `route_id` is available on every row

Comment: many thanks. do I need to remove the date in front of the time? I want to get the averages of each time interval across the entire month (i.e. 30 sample days)

Comment: There needs more adjustment. 1).  date distinction needs to be removed, since I am interested to capture the average weight per time interval across the entire month (i.e. 30 sample days)  2). the time intervals are not continuous from the result. It only displays time intervals where there are parcels. I need to display all time intervals and if there is no parcel just report 0.