# Multiple elif statements and logic to populate dataframe

Tags: python, if-statement

I am having difficulty figuring out the logic and flow of a problem. I have a dataframe with start times and end times of certain events over a period of many minutes (the real dataframe is huge). I want to find out how many of those events (i.e. offsets) occurred in each minute.

```
   onset = pd.Dataframe([30.1,41.3,71.3,119.1,148.3,185.1],index= index)
   offset = pd.DataFrame([32.1,45.3,78.3,121.1,150.3,190.1],index= index)
   timestamps = pd.concat(onset, offset], axis=1)


n=1
seconds = 60
offset_df = []
for offset in timestamps['offset']:
    if offset < seconds: 
        offset_df.append({'clip_offset': offset, 'seconds': seconds}) 
    elif seconds <= offset <= seconds+60:  # 180 < 150ms < 120
        seconds = seconds + 60 
        offset_df.append({'clip_offset': offset, 'seconds': seconds})
    elif offset > seconds+60: 
        new_n = offset / seconds
        n+=int(new_n)
        seconds = 60*n
        offset_df.append({'clip_offset': offset, 'seconds': seconds})
```

I know my logic about updating 'seconds' is incorrect and I know I need a contingency in the event that there aren't any offset events in a given 60 second chunk.

Expected output:

```
onset   offset   seconds
30.1    32.1     60 
41.3    45.3     60
71.3    78.3     120
119.1   121.1    180
148.3   150.3    180
185.1   190.1    240
```

Comment: The code you posted needs some love.  there are a couple syntax errors and undefined things.  If you can clean it up a bit, the problem would be clearer.

timestamps = ...
timestamps['offset']  ??

Comment: this really seems like where you want to get to, by the way...  especially if you can get your data into proper DateTime objects!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458/how-to-group-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-defined-time-interval

Comment: thanks, took this from a much larger script so had to modify. anyways, changed variable names now and it should be clearer.

Comment: Will I be able to convert to a datetime object if all I have is the relative timestamp from the beginning of the event, and not date?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output, as well as clarify what the input is?

Comment: yes, clarified the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your secondary question about using relative timestamp and transitioning to `datetime` objects... YES.  You will need to have some basic familiarity with both the `datetime` object which holds the time and `timedelta` objects which are used for arithmetic on times.  And some patience because dealing with dates and times is the major PITA of any programming language.  Realize that under the hood the `datetime` object is just a counter.  So you can set it in several ways, and then just use `timedelta` to augment it.  Here is an example:

```
In [6]: from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                

In [7]: ref_start = datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=22)                        

In [8]: ref_start                                                               
Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 22, 0, 0)

In [9]: ref_start.isoformat()                                                   
Out[9]: '2020-03-22T00:00:00'

In [10]: ref_start.astimezone()                                                 
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 22, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200), 'PDT'))

In [11]: elapsed_seconds = [3, 5, 112.19, 34.6, 20000, 900000]                  

In [12]: ref_starts_datetime = [ref_start + timedelta(seconds=t) for t in elapse
    ...: d_seconds]                                                             

In [13]: for start in ref_starts_datetime: 
    ...:     print(start.isoformat()) 
    ...:                                                                        
2020-03-22T00:00:03
2020-03-22T00:00:05
2020-03-22T00:01:52.190000
2020-03-22T00:00:34.600000
2020-03-22T05:33:20
2020-04-01T10:00:00
```

Alternate approach using dummy column...

```
In [14]: data = {'onset':[30.1,41.3,71.3,119.1,148.3,185.1], 
    ...:         'offset':[32.1,45.3,78.3,121.1,150.3,190.1]}                   

In [15]: import pandas as pd                                                    

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)                                                

In [17]: df                                                                     
Out[17]: 
   onset  offset
0   30.1    32.1
1   41.3    45.3
2   71.3    78.3
3  119.1   121.1
4  148.3   150.3
5  185.1   190.1

In [18]: df['epoch'] = df['offset']//60                                         

In [19]: df                                                                     
Out[19]: 
   onset  offset  epoch
0   30.1    32.1    0.0
1   41.3    45.3    0.0
2   71.3    78.3    1.0
3  119.1   121.1    2.0
4  148.3   150.3    2.0
5  185.1   190.1    3.0

In [20]: df['epoch'] = df['epoch'].astype(int)                                  

In [21]: df                                                                     
Out[21]: 
   onset  offset  epoch
0   30.1    32.1      0
1   41.3    45.3      0
2   71.3    78.3      1
3  119.1   121.1      2
4  148.3   150.3      2
5  185.1   190.1      3

In [22]: df.groupby('epoch').count()                                            
Out[22]: 
       onset  offset
epoch               
0          2       2
1          1       1
2          2       2
3          1       1

In [23]: df.groupby('epoch')['epoch'].count()                                   
Out[23]: 
epoch
0    2
1    1
2    2
3    1
Name: epoch, dtype: int64

In [24]: results = _                                                            

In [25]: type(results)                                                          
Out[25]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [26]:
```

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's really necessary to convert all of the offset timestamps to datetime objects to accomplish this task, it seems superfluous and like I should just be able to count how many offset events occur in each interval of 60 without going through this trouble

Comment: OK, true.  I'm not sure if there is a way to torture the `pandas.groupby` to group by intervals other than times (like above).  The other approach that comes to mind that is pretty easy is to just create a dummy column that is the minute that the event is tagged in and then use groupby on that.  That would be easy, using modulo 60 on your seconds.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be easiest! So the modulo would be `offset % seconds`? And then yes, easy to group by that once I have a `seconds` columns

Comment: Oooops, I misspoke above.  You want to do integer division, not modulo.  So, something like 400.2 seconds is `400.2//60` = 6.  You can compute this new column by applying this math operation to the offsets column.  Then, yes, groupby and sum.  If you aren't familiar with groupby, search forum for examples.  If you just want the counts, it is pretty straightforward, but it can be tough to tease out the group names, etc on first try.  Tag me in comment here if you are stuck!

Comment: Yes! The integer division proved *much* simpler than all of my elif statements. For those interested, I opted for something similar to what is presented above: `df['seconds'] = ((df['offset'] // 60)*60)+60` and then  
    `cts = df.groupby("seconds").seconds.agg('count').to_frame('counts').reset_index()` and then a simple merge. Thank you!

Comment: @MeC I would also suggest that you convert your `seconds` column to an integer.  You should not have any decimal dust from the math that would cause problems with groupby, but I would not fully trust that.