# Pandas Group by and Resample together?

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner at Python but have managed to massage some data into a DataFrame that I am trying to analyse

The data consists of 4 columns, and each line records the start time of a system function, the server it was on, the function name and the duration of the function call

Timestamp - datetimeindex
server - string
function - string
duration - timedelta

What I am trying to output is a 5 minute breakdown showing the max, min and mean of each function within those five minutes.  The idea being to track trends over time and find times of day where certain functions run slow.

Anyway, I am struggling to code a display of this.  I would appreciate some pointers in the right direction!

I have tried to read the docs for the Groupby and resample functions but they are a bit over my head

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255458) on Pandas grouping by time interval.

Comment: When I run something like df.resample('5min') it jsut prints out "<bound method GroupBy.mean of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x00000172C79C0770>>" instead of the results of that work. Not sure how to get at the actual result. This is my general lack on python knowlede showing...

Comment: If I do result=df.resample('5min')
print(result) then I get <bound method GroupBy.mean of <pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x00000182E3BA3EC0>>


DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<5 * Minutes>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, origin=start_day] .

Comment: Different output, but still no actual result of that operation

Comment: ok, I'm having a play and making small progress

Comment: If you get stuck then provide a minimum example of data as a DF constructor (few time intervals and one other column). The approach in the Link should be OK.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.